# Haskell cata types

Tags: haskell, catamorphism, recursion-schemes

After reading (and implementing) part of http://blog.sumtypeofway.com/recursion-schemes-part-2/  I still wonder how the types in the `cata` function work. The `cata` function is defined as:

```
mystery :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Term f -> a
mystery f = f . fmap (mystery f) . unTerm
```

I have something like `Term Expr`. After unpacking I get `Expr (Term Expr)`. The algebra (`f`) is defined e.g. as `f :: Expr Int -> Int`. I know I could call the following easily:

```
x = Literal "literal" :: Expr a
f :: Expr Int -> Int
f x :: Int
```

I can also imagine:

```
x = Literal "literal" :: Expr (Term Expr)
f :: Expr a -> Int
f x :: Int
```

But the following I suppose wouldn't work:

```
x = Literal "literal" :: Expr (Term Expr)
f :: Expr Int -> Int
f x :: ???
```

However, I still don't get how it works in the `cata` function - how do I get from `Expr (Term Expr)` to `Expr a`. I understand that the values do work, but I just don't get the types - what happens in the leaves of the tree? This is indeed a `mystery`...

Edit: I'll try to state more clearly what I don't understand.

Mentally, the `cata` seems to work this way:

- Apply `fmap f` to leaves.
- Now I have `Expr Int` and I can call `fmap f` to the node I have and get way up.

It doesn't obviously work this way as I am applying `fmap (cata f)`. However, ultimately the function `f` gets called with `Expr Int` as an argument (in the leaves). How was this type produced from `Expr (Term Expr)` that it was before?

Comment: You can't really define a meaningful `f :: Expr a -> Int`.

Comment: Sure you can: `f (Literal str) = length str`

Comment: seems your `f` is not a total function anymore ... what about `f (Paren ...)`?

Comment: That's not very meaningful: what about all the other cases? There's no way to exploit the generic `a` to affect the `Int` result.

Comment: That's the trick with catamorphism - it looks as if somewhere inside the function in the leaves there was something like `fmap (undefined :: a -> Int) x`. Then you can defined `f (Parens a b) = a + b` because the `a` and `b` are Ints.

Comment: what happens with the leaves depends on what `f` has to say to it - `mystery` is there to handle the *folding* for you

Comment: Carsten, that's right. What I don't understand is how the leaves get converted from type `Expr (Term Expr)`  into `Expr a`.

Comment: No, you can't write `f (Parens a b) = a+b` unless `f :: Expr Int -> Int`. The point is that `a,b` have the type which is argument to `Expr`. (BTW, `Paren` takes only one argument, but let's ignore that -- that's not the point)

Comment: The point is that f is `f :: Expr Int -> Int`. That's why it's a `mystery`.

Comment: I really can't understand the question, then. My point is: if `f :: Expr Int -> Int`, then `mystery f :: Term Expr -> Int` will do all the folding. If `f :: Expr a -> Int`, then `f` is constrained by parametricity to be practically useless. We _can_ still use `mystery f`, but in practice it will be almost useless.

Comment: right now it's hard to formulate as you seem to have strayed from the `newtype Term f = In { out :: f (Term f) }` definition used in your linked article. If you add the missing definitions and give a correct term then I can show you how it just unfolds using `mystery` - but really you can do yourself - take a paper right it down and then just *reduce* ;)

Comment: By the way, the leaves don't get converted from `Expr (Term Expr)` into `Expr a` -- what makes you think that's the case?

Comment: @chi I think OP has trouble seeing where the `f` really *happens* finally

Comment: I tried to edit the question to make it more clear where I have the problem. Carsten - yes, that's probably the trouble I have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how `cata` operates on leaves.

Assume `f :: Expr Int -> Int`. Then:

```
cata f :: Term Expr -> Int
fmap (cata f) :: Expr (Term Expr) -> Expr Int
```

Now, for any function `g :: a -> b`, we have

```
fmap g :: Expr a -> Expr b
fmap g (Literal n) = Literal n
...
```

So, on literals, `g` is immaterial. This means that, choosing `a ~ Term Expr`, `b ~ Int` and `g = cata f` we have

```
fmap (cata f) (Literal n) = Literal n  :: Term Int
f (fmap (cata f) (Literal n)) = f (Literal n) :: Int
```

So, roughly, on leaves `fmap (cata f)` is a no-op, but it changes the type from `Expr (Term Expr)` to `Expr Int`. This is a trivial transformation since `Literal n :: Expr a` for any `a`.

Comment: The last sentence is what I have been searching for. I got all the steps above, but this was missing. Thanks.